# Closing pyqt5 GUI without killing the launching Python script

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm having an issue with a Python script that launches a pyqt5 GUI.
Once the GUI is started from the launching script, the user has to provide some inputs and then close the application through a Close button. The method associated with the button ends with a "sys.exit()" to close the GUI.

The problem is that this command closes both the GUI and the launching Python script.

Is there a way to close just the GUI and not the launching script (that in my case has to do other stuff).

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Well, `sys.exit()` does indeed exit the script. Maybe look for a QT API that would exit the QT app/main loop?

Comment: Consider setting [`quitOnLastWindowClosed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop).

Answer (score 0):

Change the method to not call [sys.exit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit), which terminates the process, but rather [qApp.exit()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#exit), which only exits the qApp event loop (exec()) which you call in **main**?

Othewrise, sys.exit() raises SystemExit exception, so maybe you can catch in **main** or by overriding [QApplication.notify](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#notify).